# Does using melee weapons help ranged attacks, and vice versa?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

Let's say I've found a crossbow which has a bonus to enemy dodge chance reduction. Will that help me with my melee attacks? And let's say I have the axe skill and am duel-wielding a pair of axes. Will my increased critical chance also affect my ranged attacks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any non damage modifiers on weapons(ranged or melee and even shields) apply to the character, regardless of what attack you decide to use.

If your axe skill increases a non-damage related skill(critical chance is damage related skill), it will apply to your character.

So yes, abilities you gain from items and skills that arent damage modifiers, but other bonuses, will apply to all attacks.

Answer (score 1):

With Diggle gods, this appears to be changed - damage modifiers on melee weapons do not affect ranged damage modifiers nor vice versa (a +2 fire on a mace will not help the ranged attack damage).

Skill bonuses and penalties (primary and secondary) still affect the character rather than the particular weapon attack (a + to critical chance on a crossbow will still help critical chance on melee).

Comment: But, isn't that exactly what Skizzlefrits's answer says? Where the change?

Comment: With version 1.0.6 and prior (not sure how much further, but it is not the case with 1.0.9), damage bonuses applied to both types of attacks - a fire damage bonus on a bow would also apply to melee combat.

Answer (score 0):

I remember that several buffs are specifical to a weapon type. Enchantments over weapons, for what i know, are valid as long as you have that weapon equipped and if it's not specified otherwise, they always work.